# Want to disallow few url with the robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, nofollow, noindex

I want to block a few URLs in robots.txt, but I really don't know how to do this.

Below I have mentioned the URL, How should I disallow the dynamic URL. I really appreciate it if you help me to get rid of these doubts.

https://falgunishanepeacock.in/order-inquire?sku=FSPI-20NOVUN03LH

Answer (score 1):

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: https://falgunishanepeacock.in/order-inquire$
Disallow: https://falgunishanepeacock.in/order-inquire*
```

Test it with:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_txt?csw=1

- `*` designates 0 or more instances of any valid character.
- `$` designates the end of the URL.

Comment: Are you sure about this, I mean if I do         Disallow: /order-inquire/?*

Comment: @AltafShah use the testing tool to find out